# how to swap Token for ETH with swapExactTokensForETH() using UniswapV2Router02 Contract

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, etherscan

i'm traying to swap some DAI for ETH on the Ropsten Network using the UniswapV2Router02 on Etherscan (Ropsten Test Network).

DAI Address on Ropsten = 0xad6d458402f60fd3bd25163575031acdce07538d
WETH = 0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab

in my Wallet i have 2000 DAI (Ropsten)

but when i put the data there. like this:
[image]

Metamask shows that there is an Error thrown by the Contract.
So i might be missing something or am'i doing it wrong.

[image]

can please someone help and show me how can i make a successful transaction there ?

Answer (score 5):

i got this to work.
if someone is interested to know how, here is what i have done.

1- `amountIn` should be in 10^18, that means 100 was wrong, it should be 100x10^18 = 100**000000000000000000**

2- first i had to approve the UniswapRouterAddress to spend this 100 DAI.
so on the DAI contract Address i had to put the data like this:

[image]

after that i was able t swap the 100 DAI for ETH (as much as 100 DAI is worth of ETH)